# How to show or hide a textbox in asp.net based on two dates in page load event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webform with label,2 datepicker and a textbox.I have a date value in label.On page load if datepicker selected value is less than label value,i want to show textbox,else hide it.How can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Variable for taking datepicker selected value shows null reference error when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first set your textbox **visible** properties to false and do following.

```
var dateFromLabel = lablel.text; 
var dateFromPicker = DateTime.Now;
```

**Now, Convert this string to DateTime format which you get from datepicker i.e.**

```
DateTime dateFromLabelConverted = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFromLabel);
if (dateFromPicker < dateFromLabelConverted )
{
textbox.visible = true;
}
```

**Note:** if date format does  not matche it may not gives you proper result.

Comment: var dateFromPicker shows a null reference error when the page loads.When page loads first time var dateFromPicker is always NULL.How can i handle that

Comment: set the default  value to date picker  when page loads i.e.  `dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now`. Also i improved it in answer too.

Comment: I have two datepickers and if we give default value,we did not get expected result.

Comment: we can use IsPostBack method but next time when i select only one datepicker the other shows null reference error.

Comment: Its mean you want to have value in both date picker ? if  then assign date to both date picker with different date.

Comment: " if date format does not matche it may not gives you proper result." DateTime does not have a format. It is only formatted when turned into a string for display.